# Bearer Authorization, 400 error from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, bearer-token

I am trying the following in Angular:

```
    $http({
        url : "http://app.test.com/app/yyyy",
        method : "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0VUh6UHF4ZEVLanhLdEtuaG1Vc2haQ2hSSHJGcElnWCIsImlzcyI6IjcyLjIyNC4xODMuMTk4IiwiZXhwIjoxNDQ5ODgxNTEzLCJpYXQiOjE0NDg2NzE5MTN9.euiwxaXiVIbyT1-AsA1r2kIDTWgxJBNdvSLM7c5n558"
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

And I am getting the following:
[image: error]

And this error from the server: http://prntscr.com/98el4s

The following curl is working:

curl 'http://app.test.com/app/yyyy' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://app.test.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ko;q=0.6' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ5Ykdlb0VwZ0V1ZllISGVNWkFkZGJrVmh0TVhMY25oUiIsImlzcyI6IjcyLjIyNC4xODMuMTk4IiwiZXhwIjoxNDUwMDI4NjAyLCJpYXQiOjE0NDg4MTkwMDJ9.SD0knQ8PbFP820XX_CuZBQ549VfPJyoTSqajZhvZFGU'  --data-binary '563'

Comment: Where is that token value originally from? Is that a JWT?

Comment: I am using the following library: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer (if it helps)

Comment: I added a working Curl that is currently working

Answer (score 1):

I had to specific a some sort of data payload using "data: ''" to make it work.

Not sure why but did the trick!